# BeyondCompare - How to generate compare report in command line?

Tags: python, beyondcompare, beyondcompare4

I'm using BeyondCompare 4 on Linux, and my goal is to generate a compare result from command line and then use this result in python or some other scripts.

I have tried to use `bcompare @"script.txt" file1 file2 result.txt`. Which `script.txt` is:

```
file-report layout:side-by-side output-to:%3 %1 %2
```

But the result's format is difficult to parse with other scripts.

Question: How could I generate two texts like the ones showing in BeyondCompare's GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script appears to be correct, but Beyond Compare on Linux requires an X-Window session to run, even for a script. This means it will fail to launch if you run a script in an SSH terminal without an X-Window client configured or if you run it as a cron job.

Beyond Compare on macOS has a similar GUI requirement for scripts.

Beyond Compare on Windows isn't dependent on a GUI for scripts, so it will run as a scheduled task without a user logged on.

Removing the X-Window/GUI dependency for Beyond Compare scripts on Linux and macOS is on the todo list.

Comment: I also find a bug about `bcompare` command. Sometimes strange file name cause fail compare result.

Comment: Please email an example of problem file names to support@scootersoftware.com.